# Тире между цифрами в регулярном выражении, шаблон ввода

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по регуляркам.

Шаблон ^[0-9]+$ позволяет вводить любые цифры, шаблон ^[0-9-]+$ позволяет вводить любые цифры и тире. А как сделать так, чтобы тире можно было вводить только между цифрами? '123-456' правильно, а, например, '-123' — не правильно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для произвольного количества цифр:

```
^\d+-\d+$
```

> 4566-2423424

Для ограниченного количества цифр:

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}$
```

> 111-222